# Перевести числа в денежный формат (1 000, 10 000 и т.д.)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Нужно чтобы, при вводе цифр в input число преобразовывалось в формат 1 000, 10 000, 100 000 и т.д.

```
<input type="number" min="0" ng-model="credits.income" required>
```

Comment: Судя по всему вам нужно не формат данных, а маску ввода сделать на поле, посмотрите в строну angular-ui-mask

Comment: `(10000).toLocaleString({currency: "RUB"}` - можно попробовать что-то типа такого. Правда насчет поддержки браузерами ничего точно не могу сказать.

Answer (score 1):

**При вводе:**

Используйте, например: [`angular-money-mask`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-money-mask).

**При выводе:**

Используйте фильтр `currency`:

```
{{credits.income | currency: "символ валюты"}}
```